# All is moved to the right (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have a problem creating a notepad on python. When I added the separator line everything was shifted to the right. I think it's a frame problem. I wrote it all into a function in a second tab since it appears once a key is pressed from the base tab.

```
from tkinter import *

def open_documento ():
    def titolo ():
        x = widget_titolo.get("1.0",END)
        finestra_documento.title(x)
    
    finestra_documento = Tk()
    finestra_documento.geometry("500x500")
    finestra_documento.config()
 
          #FRAMES
    
    fram1 = Frame(finestra_documento,width=140,height=87)
    fram1.grid(column=0,row=0)

    fram2 = Frame(finestra_documento,width=140,height=87)
    fram2.grid(column=1,row=0)


    fram5= Frame(finestra_documento,width=10,height=15)
    fram5.grid(row=1,column=0)

    fram6 = Frame(finestra_documento,width=500,height=400,bg="red")
    fram6.grid(row=2,column=0)

    linea_separatrice = Label(fram5,text="---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    linea_separatrice.grid(column=0,row=0)

    #       WIDGET
    
    tasto_indietro = Button(fram1,text="<",height=2,font=("Arial",12))
    tasto_indietro.grid(column=0,row=0)

    widget_titolo = Text(fram1,height=2,width=22,highlightthickness=0)
    widget_titolo.grid(row=0,column=1)
    widget_titolo.insert("1.0","Titolo")

    tasto_titolo = Button(fram2,text="Inserisci il titolo",command=titolo)
    tasto_titolo.grid(row=0,column=0)
    
    contenuto = Text(fram6,width=70,height=350,highlightthickness=0)
    contenuto.pack()
```